# How can I save the ListView's scroll position

Tags: android

How can I save the ListView's scroll position when I choose one item in ListView, and I want to return back in same ListView .

Suppose we have two fragments – ListFragment and SomeOtherFragment. We replace ListFragment with SomeOtherFragment.

```
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you click on row of `ListFragment`, save the position in SharedPreference

```
<shared_pref_object>.putInt("scroll_position",position);
```

Use this when you come back from `OtherFragment` -> `ListFragment`

```
<editor_obj>.getInt("scroll_position",0);
```

set this as scroll position :

```
listview.setSelection(<editor_obj>.getInt("scroll_position",0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder why for this common problem there is no good and optimized solution. As I saw, everyone have solved it in one's own way. but I wanna present my own way after trying all of them:

Within the ListFragment declare two int variables to hold the scroll position:

```
public static class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

        private int listIndex = -1;
        private int listTop = 0;
```

Then override the onPause() and onResume() to save and restore the `ListView`'s scroll positions as follows:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

   //after setting adapter and your arbitrary codes
      if(listIndex!=-1){
         this.getListView().setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
      }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      try {
        listIndex = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = getListView().getChildAt(0);
        listTop = (v != null) ? v.getTop() : 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Wish to diminish the pains!! :blush: